# Why AFNetworking successfully works without internet connection?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, internet-connection

When I complete this code first time without internet connection it shows alert how it should to. But when I complete it first successfully with internet connection and then switched internet connection off than all next executions will complete with success with the same respond object. Haven't tried it on device, only iOS Simulator.

```
NSString *string = @"https://money.yandex.ru/api/categories-list";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self deleteAllObjects];
    self.numberOfBranchObjects = 0;
    for (NSString *key in (NSDictionary *)responseObject) {
        [self insertNewObject:key fromSender:self];
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}];
[operation start];
```

Is it any cache at AFNetworking for responded objects or smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it does cache, here you go:

```
[operpation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
    return nil;
}];
```

I recommend you test the internet connection directly, though, before requests.

You'd do that by putting this in an initialization part of your view controller:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

Then just call this method before:

```
- (BOOL)connected {
    return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Bulls eye! Works as I wanted.